# Parsing time data and formatting the output

Tags: python

I have a text file with start and end time (of audio tracks)
in the format 54.60('\t')60.52 this is in seconds on its own line, there is a further 7 entries in the txt file.
I need to convert these seconds (using `datetime.timedelta`) I think into their respective minute representations.

I then need to:

1. maintain original layout format of start and end time on one line only and
2. append 01, 02, etc to the end of each line

P.S. I have already managed to parse the file and convert the txt file into a list of converted values.

This is the function I have so far:

```
import datetime
def compute(s :  str):
    list_vals = []
    for line in s.split():
        line_val = float(line)
        secs = datetime.timedelta(seconds = int(line_val))
        list_vals.append(str(secs))
    with open ('new_secs.txt', 'w') as a:
        for list_item in list_vals:
            a.write('%s\t' % list_item)
    return list_vals
```

This is the input in my txt file

```
64.870000   2880.150000
3239.940000 5760.150000
6119.920000 8994.314240
9719.920000 10440.150000
10799.930000    12960.160000
13679.920000    17567.020000
```

This is the output that is returned form the function in a new txt file

```
['0:01:04', '0:48:00', '0:53:59', '1:36:00', '1:41:59', '2:29:54', '2:41:59', '2:54:00', '2:59:59', '3:36:00', '3:47:59', '4:52:47']
```

I was wondering if what i have done so far is correct and what are my next steps in achieving steps 1 and 2 above.

Comment: What output does your code produce? Best thing to do would be to edit the code in your question to be a [mre] with imports and some example data, so anyone who wants can paste your code into a file and _without adding anything else_ run the code to see the same results as you.

Comment: Barny thanks for being gentle with my first post ever, i will do as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have the right idea, but I think you should do it in two steps:

1. Convert the values on each line into a pair of `timedelta`s,
2. Write the converted data to a output file and affix a counter value to the end of each line.

Python has a handy built-in function named [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which helps with counting a sequence of things, so I've used that to eliminate the bookkeeping normally associated with creating and maintaining a separate counter.

```
import datetime

with open('times.txt') as inp, open ('new_secs.txt', 'w') as outp:
    for i, line in enumerate(inp, start=1):
        pair = []
        for value in line.split()[:2]:  # First two values.
            line_val = float(value)
            secs = datetime.timedelta(seconds=round(line_val))
            pair.append(str(secs))
        outp.write('\t'.join(pair + [f'{i:02d}']) + '\n')

print('done')
```

Contents of `new_secs.txt` afterwards (with `»` representing tab characters):

```
0:01:05»0:48:00»01
0:54:00»1:36:00»02
1:42:00»2:29:54»03
2:42:00»2:54:00»04
3:00:00»3:36:00»05
3:48:00»4:52:47»06
```

Comment: thanks for the help it was spot on i genuinely mean that, because i wasn't expecting the full answer maybe just some pointers was what i should of said in my original post., i sort of guessed it would need two lists and a nested for loop to achieve my goal but i really haven't the confidence with python just yet, again thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I've modified my answer so it no longer requires using two lists because it reads the input and writes the output file in simultaneously within a single outer-most `for` loop.

Comment: Sir you have done more than enough already, there was really no need but i will thank you again.